# android dialogs UX experience - two list views or spinners in one dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-spinner

I'm working on one dialog. It should have two listviews either two spinners either one spinner and one listview. The list on items in the second depends on the choice in the first one. And now I have dilemma concerning graphical user interface.

When I put two elements (ex. spinner and listview) in one dialog window it's looks awful and it's difficult for using. How to solve that? What would you recommend? If I use two different dialog windows, it will be difficult to switch between two lists, as I imagine that the user can change few times the selected option in the first list until he/she decides what to select from the second list.

Any suggestion? Perhaps you saw some nice solution in one of apps in the market?

Answer (score 1):

you can either show it in two different dialogs without disturbing the UX 
or 
Why not try something like [This](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/wheel-widget/) or [This](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel)

Comment: Thank you. That's interesting proposal but I would prefer not to use external widgets in my app.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of widgets out there (both from android itself and custom ones)  that would solve your needs for showing the info. However I think that your problem is not the 2 lists but the dialog.

For a better user experience I recommend using an appearing/sliding-in layout or a prompt screen. An appearing layout is the one that appears below your "change this" title. It's not so disturbing as you can keep using the whole screen, you can add animations, you can customize it a lot to fit your app design... If your space is limited, you can always show a hidden layout containing your views. this method is a little more disturbing so fits better if you are starting a separate action, not filling information as the underlying views.

Comment: Thank for your answer. As I'm beginner in Android, I'm not sure if I understand you well. Could you give any example, ex from Internet please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725966/android-expandable-menu-hiding-unhiding-menu